# Right-Click deleting in DataGrid from Dictionary<> in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, datagrid, mouseevent

I have a DataGrid which receives it's values from a dictionary as such:

```
public class Files
        {
            public string File { get; set; }
            public string Duration { get; set; }
            public string Status { get; set; }           
        }

        Dictionary<Files, string> files = new Dictionary<Files, string>(); 
        DataGrid.ItemsSource = files.Keys;
```

Values are added programatically like this:

```
private void AddFilesList(string addsrc, string addduration, string addstatus, string path)
        {
            files.Add(new Files
            {
                File = addsrc,
                Duration = addduration,
                Status = addstatus,

            }, path
               );
            DataGrid.Items.Refresh();  
        }
```

Now I am trying to add right-click/delete to the DataGrid which would delete the selected value from Dictionary.

I use MVVM pattern to delete the value as such, here is the XAML:

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource EmpVM}}">
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="287" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,12,0,0" 
              Name="DataGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="657" 
              SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=RecordIndex,Mode=TwoWay}">
            <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding RecordIndex}"  Header="Delete"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

Now the problem is that "Selectedindex" reflects the index of the selected value, and Dictionary<> does not have an index. This I am not able to remove the selecteditem after Index. I can't use OrderedDictionary either since I have to load a class into the dictionary.

Any suggestions anyone on how to bind the XAML to remove the selected item from Dictionary?

Comment: Have you tried: `files.Remove(files.Keys[SelectedIndex])`

Comment: Why not to use SelectedItem or SelectedValue and files.Remove()?

Comment: It's still index as an int.

Comment: Dev: Because it's loaded from a Class, so using selected value doesn't show the current value within the class, but just the general class.